# How to Fix Not Found Error with Heroku Deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, webdeploy

I am new to web-development and am having some issues deploying my very basic website with Heroku. Upon creating my app, I have successfully pushed my app to git and deployed it to Heroku. Also, it does run locally just fine.

However, upon opening the app (using "Heroku open" command and clicking the "Open app" button on the Heroku app page itself), I am getting a page that says **Not Found**.

I have been searching for a solution all over and would really appreciate some help here. Thank you.

**Procfile:**

```
web: node server.js
```

**package.json:**

```
 {                                                                               
   "name": "LHSite",                                                           
   "version": "1.0.0",                                                         
   "engines": {                                                                
       "node": "13.12.x"                                                       
   },                                                                          
   "scripts": {                                                                
       "start": "node server.js"                                               
   },                                                                          
   "dependencies": {                                                           
      "express": "4.17.1"                                                     
   },                                                                          
   "author": "Hunter Estrada",                                                 
   "license": "ISC"
 }
```

**server.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("/Users/<user>/CS/LHSite/Apr29Home.html");
}
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("app running");
}
```

**File structure:**
[file structure for my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wfGO.png)

Here is the url for my app: https://lh-anni-2.herokuapp.com

Comment: share your herokuapp url

Comment: Just edited the question and included the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The express.static middleware is separate from res.sendFile, You need to 
   use an absolute path directly with res.sendFile. you can do it:

1. make a public directory in current project folder and put you html file there.
2. include path module in the server.js file like

`const path = require('path');`

3. replace your res.sendFile with below line of code

`res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'Apr29Home.html'));`

Note: __dirname returns the directory that the currently executing script is in.

Comment: Thank you, that was able to get something up onto the url. However, even though I put all my css and html files into the public folder, only some of my styling is showing up, and links to other html files I had created are not able to be accessed. Do you know why this is?

Comment: replace app.use(express.static(__dirname));
with app.use(express.static('public')); // or your static files folder name

Comment: Thanks so much. Really appreciate it.